# Google Plus Button Android hide the recommended text

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using google plus button in my app. I declared it in xml like:

```
om.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
                xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
                android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                plus:annotation="inline"
                plus:size="standard" />
```

And in my class:

```
mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
mPlusOneButton.initialize(URL, 5);
```

But it is also displaying an image and the text "+287 including You". I want it to display only google+ button and I want it not to display the image and text. How to do this?

Screenshot:
  [image]

Comment: What happens when you set annotation to none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/

None doesnt set anything next to the button
Bubble sets the number of people (the +1) 
Inline sets everything

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted